# Cómo iterar elementos HTMLElement usando Renderer2 en Angular

Tags: html, angular7

según veo en Angular lo recomendable es usar Renderer2 para manipular elementosHTML, en mi html cargo un listado de objetos con *ngFor que se visualiza en

pero me estoy encontrando con un obstáculo al programar un boton que limpie algo en específico de los objetos de lista en mi caso.

```
    antiguo:HTMLElement;
    elmsSeleccionados:Array<HTMLElement>;//<- 1er opción usar un array
planactive:string;//<- 2da opcion con ngClass
      constructor(...Renderer2) {
    }
    mostrarActivo(elemento:HTMLElement){ /* HTMLElement requerido p manejar el Render2*/
        if(this.antiguo){
          this.renderer.removeClass(this.antiguo,'destacado');
            
        }
      
      this.renderer.addClass(elemento,'destacado');/* así mantengo encapsulamiento*/
      
      let nuevoElemento=this.renderer.createElement("span");
      this.renderer.setProperty(nuevoElemento,"innerHTML"," ")//<- ésta marca quiero quitar con el boton
      this.renderer.appendChild(elemento,nuevoElemento);
    
      this.antiguo=elemento;
      this.elmsSeleccionados.push(elemento);//intentaba ir almacenando itms HTML

    //luego tengo mi evento para el boton:
    resetActivo(){
       /* for (var elem in this.elmsSeleccionados)
        {
          console.log(elem);*/
        let nuevoElemento=this.renderer.selectRootElement("span");
      //this.renderer.removeClass('destacado',milemento);
      this.renderer.setProperty(nuevoElemento,"innerHTML","");//<- en teoría así se elimina,no existe un metodo removeProperty en Angular
       /* }*/
        }
```

Quiero que el botón cancelar quite la marca(Property)y modifique la class para cada objeto

en mi pagina.

```
<input type="button" enabled value="Cancelar"  (click)="resetActivo()" #cancelabtn>`
```

No sé porque no se guarda en mi array,cómo sería la técnica para ello?
Anexo html:

```
<div class="card-container">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let plan of planes" [ngClass]="planactive"(click)="mostrarActivo(aseguraelem)" #aseguraelem>{{plan.nombre}}</li>
    </ul>
    <input type="button" disabled value="Tu vida está en riesgo" #asegurabtn> &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" enabled value="Cancelar"  (click)="resetActivo()" #cancelabtn>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola. Lo que buscas se puede resolver fácilmente en tu html con un `*ngClass` y un `*ngFor`. En mi opinion, es mas complicado (este caso) resolverlo con `renderer2`. Puedes mostrar el html que quieres lograr para hacerte un ejemplo por este método?

Comment: @Legna agregué  mi html, es simple,pero aún no estoy seguro de cómo usar ngClass

Comment: Hasta ahora logré asignar la clase dinámica con : <li *ngFor="let plan of planes" [ngClass]="planactive"  .>, pero tengo pendiente la removeProperty(), cómo  quitar una propiedad/atributo dinámicamente?

Comment: Que propiedad quieres quitar? Puedes actualizar tu pregunta con lo que has hecho?

Comment: Hice un experimento interesante, tratando de seleccionar el rootElement de <ul > pero desaparece los elementos con solo declarar una variable. aquí el video: http://srecorder.com/s/9fab

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, lo he logrado! ,la verdad no hay mucha documentación al respecto y no encontré la solución ahí, lo único que comenta es que el método ElementRef es vulnerable, siempre que podamos usar Rerderer2 hagámoslo. En mi caso tube que declarar el array como `elmsSeleccionados: HTMLElement[]=[];`
y una vez capturado el html usando `this.elmsSeleccionados.push(elemento);`  ya lo que restaba es hechar mano de javascript recordar que los objetos Node tienen una propiedad firstElementChild, así que la instrucción queda: `this.renderer.removeChild(this.elmsSeleccionados[i],this.elmsSeleccionados[i].firstElementChild);`  espero le sirva.